# Is frequent use of bind(this) in Javascript a code smell?

Tags: javascript, code-smell

I am doing a project for a client where I am getting my first real heavy, hands-on exposure with Javascript.

Since I have learned about adding `.bind(this` to callback functions, I find I am doing it everywhere, and I wonder whether it is excessive and whether it's good practice, or whether I am structuring my code badly.

Is it normal to have `.bind(this)` on nearly every callback?

Comment: A code smell implies that there is a better way to perform the same action. Is there a better way to perform the same action?

Comment: @Kain0_0 I don't know whether there is. I lack the know-how. Like I said, this is my first real hands-on exposure to Javascript (aside from just tinkering over the years).

Comment: `bind(this)` is a lanugage-smell, that's it's jank and broken and definitely not worthy of its nomination for "universally runnable language" lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you pretty much need to do this. If you call the functions of an object from the prototype, the `this` won't be bound to the object you call it on.

By doing `this.fooMethod = fooMethod.bind(this);`, you're making the object have its own instance method store a bound version of `fooMethod`. Calling `fooMethod` on that object will now call the function from its instanve variable, not from its prototype, with `this` appropriately bound.

The only real alternative is to use arrow notation, instead:

```
this.fooMethod = () => fooMethod();
```

But it gets repeated ad nauseam, just the same.

Comment: Thanks! That tells me all I need to know. I was worried that, because I find myself doing it so often, I must be doing something wrong. I have not come across this in other languages, but maybe it's because they don't rely on callbacks so much(?)

Comment: @mydoghasworms Nah, it's just because every other language (that I know of) has method references that are either unbound (and need to be bound to a target object, by some means), or bound (already have the target object set). JS is the only language I know of in which has unbound method references, for this `this` is implicitly set (almost always to the wrong thing)